# Add data to request is not working in backpack for laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

In my crud controller I have added this code inside `store` method:

```
$this->crud->getRequest()->request->add(['author_id'=> backpack_user()->id]);
```

The `author_id` is also available in `fillable` property of Model.
But, `author_id` is not added to the database.

If I add a hidden field in `createOperation` method, that works fine.
Why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to use Model events for this scenario and not overwriting the `store()` function.

You can add in your `setupCreateOperation()` or in `setup()`:

```php
$this->crud->model::saving(function($entry) { 
    $entry->author_id = backpack_user()->id;
});
```

Cheers